# Is there a shorter version, biased probability?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, random, probability

```
import random as rd
def prob(times):
    h,t=0,0
    for _ in range(times):
        if rd.randrange(1,11)<=7:h+=1
        else:t+=1
    return h
```

**To return the results of biased coin flipping 70% head**

Comment: To get a 70% chance of True, you just need `return rd.random() <= 0.7`.

Comment: like to flip a coin 1000 times and get head about 700 times.

Comment: This code doesn't simulate a coin, it simulates a 10-sided die.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to python, I will improve my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you only return `h`, you don't actually need `t`. It is also not needed to use `randrange` -- you can achieve the same with `random`.

For the actual counting you can use `sum`, and the boolean result can be converted to 0 or 1 with `int`:

```
def prob(times):
    return sum(int(rd.random() < 0.7) for _ in range(times))
```

Or in lambda notation:

```
prob = lambda times: sum(int(rd.random() < 0.7) for _ in range(times))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply

Comment: You don't even need to use `int()` to convert booleans, the `bool` type is a subclass of `int`.